# How to insert data from database into Jquery script

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, database

I am working on a ASP.NET/C# web application.
I am writing a Jquery script.
I would like to know what is the best way to add data to the script from an SQL database .
Here is a quick example showing what I would like to do:

Suppose I have a database like this

```
Name           Color
------------+---------------+
Tom            FF0000              
Kate           00FF00               
John           0000FF
```

In my script I want to do this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#main').Picture({
        colors: {Tom:'#FF0000', Kate:'#00FF00', John:'#0000FF'}
    });
});
```

the colors should be red from the database and not hard-coded.

What is the best way to insert the colors in the correct place in my code? Should I do it in a literal control and inject the script from the code behind?

### Another example:

```
$('#location').html('Here we put the text that I got from the database');
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested Scenario: Get you data from your SQL database normally like you used to, then fill the data into any web control of your choice (I prefer to use a HiddenField in this case) then the Hidden field will be available to your Javascript/jQuery code.

**Example:**
here are the steps you need to follow in order to get this problem fixed:

1- Create an  asp:HiddenField control in your page with a proper ID (ex: '**hfMyData**').

2- In your c# code, get your data from your database:

```
var mydata = // code to get the data from your Database
```

3- Fill the HiddenField value with your data:

```
hfMyData.value = mydata;
```

4- In your jQuery code `Ready()` function, use code similar to this:

```
var myDatabaseData = $("#hfMyData").val();
```

5- Now you have the data from your Database (`myDatabaseData`), use it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past (although it's a bit quick and dirty), is create a public property on the page, then call it in the jQuery using the `<% %>` tags. That way you can set the property in the code behind via the DB call, then pull them through as required.

Not very scalable, but worked well for the scenario I required (needed a twitter handle).